# method overriding with wrapper class

Tags: java

```
public class A
{
    public void display(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside A");
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public void display(Integer i)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside B");
    }
}


public class starter
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        A a = new B();
        a.display(5);
        System.out.println("So now you know or not");
    }
}
```

Output : Inside A

Can somebody explain this output? Normally child method should be called. How does Java behave here when we have a wrapper class and a primitive class using inheritance?

Comment: If Class `A` has the method defined and is not `abstract` it will call that method.

Comment: The method `B.display(Integer)` does not override `A.display(int)`. It only overloads it. `Integer` and `int` are two different types.

Comment: @3kings please look at the code again (this is Java not C++ or C# all methods are virtual by default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B#display` does **not** override `A#display`, as the signature is different.

The fact `int`s can be boxed into `Integer`s is not relevant here.

You could easily verify this by using the `@Override` annotation.

Since the reference type of `a` is `A`, the method is resolved with the exact match for a literal integer (your given `5` argument), which is `int`, therefore `A#display` is invoked.

You can still force the invocation of `B#display` by using this idiom (not for production code):

`((B)a).display(new Integer(5));`

This casts your `a` variable as a `B` type, hence allowing visibility of `B`'s `display` method within context.

It also passes an `Integer` rather than an `int`, thus employing the signature of `B`'s `display` method and allowing resolution to that method.

Comment: public static void main (String args[])
    {
        A a = new B();
        a.display(new integer(5));
        System.out.println("What will be the output now ??");
    }

Comment: output when I pass Integer instead of int in Display method is again "display of A is called". Can you explain why ?

Comment: @PriyankB since the `display` method in `B` is not overriding the one in `A`, with a given reference of `A`, `A#display` is still invoked. Also, you don't have visibility on `B#display` within context, because your reference type is `A`.